# Spinner values are not visible when a viewpager is active

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, spinner

I've setup a viewpager with 2 fragements. On first fragment, there is a spinner, which is initiated via a an ArrayAdapter to set the values for the spinner.

When I run the app without the setup of the viewpager, the spinner is shows up with the values from the ArrayAdapter, but when I complete the code with the code for the viewpager, the spinner stays empty.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, InputFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ItemFragment.class.getName()));

    .....
      strArrayList  is filled here
    .....

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_input);
    spinnerList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerList);

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strArrayList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

}
```

What can be the cause of this behouviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
 spinnerSub.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("haisp","setsubspinner11");
                spinnerSub.setSelection(savedSubPostion);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"setpost",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```